# Calculating 3 days for alarm manager trigger

Tags: android, alarmmanager

ok so I have an alarm manager that I have to go off every three days, when it goes off I write the current system time to shared preferences so that if the phone is turned off I have when it was last fired.

my question is how do I calculate 3 days from when it was last fired after the phone has been turned off since I can only write to shared preferences when its fired?

I was thinking something like this

```
long refresh = lastTime + (360000*24)*3;
```

where lastTime is when it was last fired but if the phone was restarted between then wouldnt it be another 3 days from that restart or am i thinking this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a zero missing (there are 86400000 milliseconds in a day), but other than that your approach looks fine (assuming that `lastTime` is just a stored value from `System.currentTimeMillis()`).  `AlarmManager` uses absolute times for the trigger time.

If the phone has been turned off for more than 3 days then when you restore the alarm it will be overdue and will fire immediately.  One thing to be aware of is that if you restore a repeating alarm in this way and it's been 5 days since it last fired, then when you restore it using a date in the past it will fire immediately (the overdue day 3 alarm) and then fire again after one more day (the day 6 alarm).  You may want to adjust for this.